# How to use [[ == ]] properly to match a glob?

Tags: bash, glob

Bash's manpage teaches that `[[ == ]]` matches patterns.  In Bash therefore, why does the following not print `matched`?

```
Z=abc; [[ "$Z" == 'a*' ]] && echo 'matched'
```

The following however does indeed print `matched`:

```
Z=abc; [[ "$Z" == a* ]] && echo 'matched'
```

Isn't this exactly backward?  Why does the `a*`, without the quotes, not immediately expand to list whatever filenames happen to begin with the letter a in the current directory?  And besides, why doesn't the quoted `'a*'` work in any case?

Comment: `==` is perfectly acceptable inside of `[[ ]]`, by the way, but is wrong in `[ ]` (where bash will accept it as an extension, but POSIX doesn't require it to be supported). Using `=` in all non-math-context comparisons means that your finger memory learns the POSIX-compatible approach.

Comment: @Charles I have incorporated some of what you've said in your comment into my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the existing answer is correct, I don't believe that it tells the full story.

Globs have two uses. There is a difference in behaviour between globs inside a `[[ ]]` construct which test the contents of a variable against a pattern and other globs, which expand to list a range of files. In either case, if you put quotes around character, it will be interpreted literally and not expanded.

It is also worth mentioning that the variable on the left hand side doesn't need to be quoted after the `[[`, so you could write your code like this:

```
Z=abc; [[ $Z == a* ]] && echo 'matched'
```

It is also possible to use a single `=` but the `==` looks more familiar to those coming from other coding backgrounds, so personally I prefer to use it in bash as well. As mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833482/how-to-use-properly-to-match-a-glob/25833506#comment40416975_25833482), the single `=` is the more widely compatible, as it is used to test string equality in all of POSIX-compliant shells, e.g. `[ "$a" = "abc" ]`. For this reason you may prefer to use it in bash as well.

As always, [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) contains some good information on the subject of pattern matching in bash.

Answer (score 2):

Glob pattern must not be quoted to make it work.

This should also work with just glob pattern out of quote whereas static text is still qupted:

```
[[ "$Z" == "a"* ]] && echo 'matched'
matched

[[ "$Z" == "ab"* ]] && echo 'matched'
matched
```

Explanation snippet from man page:

> When  the  == and != operators are used, the string to the right of
>   the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the 
>   rules described below under Pattern Matching.  If the shell option
>   nocasematch is enabled, the match  is  performed  without regard  to 
>   the case of alphabetic characters.  The return value is 0 if the
>   string matches (==) or does not match (!=) the  pattern, and 1
>   otherwise.  Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force it to be
>   matched as a string.

Additionally, one of the reasons to use `[[` over `[` is that `[[` is a shell built-in and thus can have its own syntax and doesn't need to follow the normal expansion rules (which is why the arguments to `[[` aren't subject to word-splitting for example).